# rosdep 0.10.22 Error 404

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed the newest version of rosdep and when I perform *rosdep update* I get the following output and the eventual error:

```
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
Ignore legacy gbpdistro "groovy"
Ignore legacy gbpdistro "hydro"
Query rosdistro index https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/rep137/releases/index.yaml
ERROR: error loading sources list:
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

I have checked and the file *https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/rep137/releases/index.yaml* does not exist.

Further information:

I have seen that what happens is that the script */usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/* when calling **rosdistro.get_index_urdl()** it is taking the function in the file */usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdistro/**init**.py* which has

```
DEFAULT_INDEX_URL = 'https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/rep137/releases/index.yaml'
```

I think that the error would not happen if the file */usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdistro/**init**.py* was taken which has

```
DEFAULT_INDEX_URL = 'https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/85681/rosdep-0.10.22-error-404/) by [Jordi Pages](https://answers.ros.org/users/626/jordi-pages/) on ROS Answers with karma: 245 on 2013-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the contents of /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list? From the error message I would guess that you have an extra line in there referring to that url.

### Edit:

Ahh you have a version from PIP overlaying the debian package.  Please repeatedly run
sudo pip uninstall rosdep
Until it says nothing to uninstall.

You should also uninstall any other ros tools in /usr/local installed via pip using the same procedure.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jordi Pages](https://answers.ros.org/users/626/jordi-pages/) on 2013-10-02**:
It does not seem so. The contents are:

## os-specific listings first

yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml osx
yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml gentoo

## generic

yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml
yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
gbpdistro https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml fuerte
gbpdistro https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/groovy.yaml groovy
gbpdistro https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/hydro.yaml hydro